# How to relate a SKOS concept as the union of two other concepts

Tags: rdf, skos

I am defining mappings between two concepts schemes, and have the following situation:

```
wp20:in a skos:Concept ;
    skos:scopeNote "A preposition or subordinating conjunction"@en .

pos:conjunction a skos:Concept .
pos:preposition a skos:Concept .
```

What I want to do is describe the scope note as RDF metadata. For example, something like:

```
wp20:in skos:exactMatch [
    a owl:unionOf ;
    skos:broadMatch pos:conjunction ;
    skos:exactMatch pos:preposition
] .
```

The above does not work as the domain and range of `skos:*Match` are `skos:Concept` objects (so it is also not possible to use `skos:Collection` types either). Additionally, the [SKOS Mapping](https://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/mapping/spec/2004-11-11.html) vocabulary is deprecated and has not been completed (although some of the mapping properties have been moved into SKOS Core).

How do I describe this relationship using SKOS vocabulary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from your comments that what you really want to state is the `wp20:in` is either a broader match of `pos:conjunction` or an exact match of `pos:preposition`.  In that case, the representation can be:

```
wp20:in skos:broadMatch pos:conjunction ;
        skos:exactMatch pos:preposition .
```

This basically states that instances of `wp20:in` is "A preposition or subordinating conjunction", with the appropriate match relationship.  That seems to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that the [SKOS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/skos-reference/) is freely available online.  I'm not much of a SKOS user, but if I encounter a question about SKOS, that's where I look first.   Some important notes that suggest that what you're looking for *might* not attainable in SKOS include:

> #### [3.5.1. SKOS Concepts, OWL Classes and OWL Properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/skos-reference/#L896)
>
> Other than the assertion that skos:Concept is an instance of
>   owl:Class, this specification does not make any additional statement
>   about the formal relationship between the class of SKOS concepts and
>   the class of OWL classes. The decision not to make any such statement
>   has been made to allow applications the freedom to explore different
>   design patterns for working with SKOS in combination with OWL.

I point that out just to say that SKOS concepts aren't the same thing as OWL classes, so saying that an SKOS concept is an exact match for an OWL class might be a bit unusual.

If it is possible, it looks like it would be somewhere in [§8. Semantic Relations](https://www.w3.org/TR/skos-reference/#semantic-relations), which specifies the kinds of relations that can exist among concepts.  It appears that the relationships that you can have are:

- skos:semanticRelation
- skos:broader
- skos:narrower
- skos:related
- skos:broaderTransitive
- skos:narrowerTransitive

Based on that list, I think that perhaps the best you could do in pure SKOS would be something like:

```
wp20:in skos:narrower pos:conjunction ,
                      pos:preposition .
```

which doesn't, I think, exactly capture what you want, but might be close enough.

Comment: I am currently using `skos:relatedMatch` as `wp20:in` is not a preposition when used as a subordinating conjunction, and vice versa. I'm using the `Match` mapping relation in the example above as the concepts are in different concept schemes. It is either `wp20:in skos:broadMatch pos:conjunction` (broader because `wp20:in` is a subordinating conjunction in this instance, and `pos:conjunction` is a broader concept) or `wp20:in skos:exactMatch pos:preposition` depending on usage (but not both at the same time).

Comment: @reece Note that owl:unionOf doesn't convey the "not at the same time", either.  E.g., If a class C is the union of A and B, then anything that is an A or a B or both is a C.   It seems like SKOS is a bit underpowered for the kind of classification you're trying to do;  if you're willing to use OWL vocabulary, is there a reason to not use an OWL ontology rather than SKOS?

Comment: SKOS best suits my usage as I am not describing specific concepts for use in RDF (i.e. I am not defining things to say "this RDF resource is a conjunction), I am describing named terms (e.g. "conj" is the notation for a "conjunction" in the part of speech vocabulary, and "j" (adjective) in the WP20 tagset is the same as "JJ" in the upenn (Penn Treebank) tagset).

Comment: Re: owl:unionOf -- I was using that as an example. http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/mapping#OR would be better (e.g. `wp20:in skos:exactMatch [ a mapping:OR ; rdf:li pos:subordinatingConjunction ; rdf:li pos:preposition ] .`, but SKOS Mapping Vocabulary has been superseded by SKOS 2009 which defines mapping relations but does not include the AND, OR and NOT classes from the SKOS mapping vocabulary.

Comment: hello @JoshuaTaylor how to coordination concept in skos? <SELL_CAR> a skos:Concept . <SELL> a skos:Concept, owl:ObjectProerty. <CAR> a skos:Concept.  and when <SELL> and <CAR> comes together it relates <SELL_CAR>. maybe <SELL_CAR> skos:exactMatch [:SELL :CAR]?